# Unable to start logstash facing permission issue

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am testing my configuration by using :

```
./logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/your_config_file.conf --config.test_and_exit
```

And getting below error :

```
[INFO ] 2020-10-15 10:25:21.481 [main] runner - Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.9.2",
 "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1 on 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04.1 +indy +jit 
[linux-x86_64]"}
[FATAL] 2020-10-15 10:25:21.586 [main] runner - An unexpected error occurred! {:error=>#
<ArgumentError: Path "/usr/share/logstash/data/queue" must be a writable directory.
 It is not writable.>, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:528:in 
`validate'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:288:in `validate_value'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:199:in `block in 
validate_all'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1415:in `each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
core/lib/logstash/settings.rb:198:in `validate_all'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-
core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:312:in `execute'", 
"/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:67:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/runner.rb:268:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/clamp-0.6.5/lib/clamp/command.rb:132:in `run'",
 "/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:88:in `<main>'"]}
[ERROR] 2020-10-15 10:25:21.589 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash 
stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

I have tried a=giving permission to logstash user to full directory by :

```
/usr/share$ sudo chown -R logstash.logstash logstash
```

But still same error. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chown` will change ownership of the directories but will not change permissions. Logstash complains that the user used for starting logstash does not have write access to `/usr/share/logstash`

`chmod` will help change the permissions. Check [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/linux-file-permissions) to understand more about the command.